# Can the tower in Hounds Pit be climbed?

Tags: dishonored

In the Hounds Pit area there is a tower that also serves as Lady Emily's room. 
When I look up in that room, there are some floorboards that you can peek through. Also the floorboards are unbreakable. 
It looks like there is a room above Emily's room, but I can't get up there. 
There seems to be an open window that leads into the room, but it's so far up that I can't reach it with Blink.

Is there a way to enter that room?

Comment: Hmm I had never noticed this before. A combination of Agility and Blink doesn't do the job? My guess then is it's impossible without hacking, modding, or cheating... Maybe pile up empty whale oil containers haha, though I don't even know if you can stand on them :P